# can't use OR in blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

When I am developing locally on win10 php7.2 nginx expression like this works just fine

```
<div class="{{ $menuclass or 'menu'}}">
```

which gives

```
<div class="menu">
```

but as soon as I deploy it via laravel forge to ubuntu machine it fails to work and I get this

```
<div class="1">
```

It seems that instead of doing this:

```
isset($menuclass ) ? $menuclass : 'menu'
```

it just returns 1

Any ideas why?

This feature was blogged about here: https://laravel-news.com/blade-or-operator

Has it been deprecated in later versions of laravel?

Comment: what version of laravel are you using?

Comment: laravel 5.7, here is compiled view file line where it fails: <div class="php echo e($menuclass or 'menu') I removed some characters so that stackoverflow shows the line. Its obvious that its not doing any isset($foo) ? $foo : 'default' as the blog post mentioned in 2014

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Laravel `or` operator was changed in laravel 5.7 to `??`

> The or Operator Likelihood Of Impact: High
>
> The Blade "or" operator has been removed in favor of PHP's built-in ??
>   "null coalesce" operator, which has the same purpose and
>   functionality:

try this:

```
<div class="{{ $menuclass ?? 'menu'}}">
```

[here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade) is the upgrade guide.